# Как использовать pool.map внутри методов класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Как использовать pool.map внутри методов класса?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class testPool:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def testMethod(self, pool):

        def func1(i):
            print(i)
            return i*i

        returnValues = pool.map(func1, range(0, 10))
        print(returnValues)



def main(pool):
    tp = testPool()
    tp.testMethod(pool)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool=Pool(processes=3)
    main(pool)
```

Ошибка:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'testPool.testMethod.<locals>.func1'
```

Comment: Лучше func1 вынести из класса полностью, или хотя бы сделать статическим методом класса - чтобы он не зависел от состояния объекта testPool. Также можно попробовать testMethod сделать методом класса (декоратор @classmethod) или статическим методом.

Comment: @insolor я согласен с вами, но для моего случая было бы оптимально использовать тот вариант кода, что я указал в посте.  Если вы знаете, можете коротко пояснить почему он не видит func1 функцию?